# Rails no route matches with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I know this question comes up a lot with Rails, but I can't seem to get any of the previous answers to work for me.

```
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :matters do
    resources :issues
  end
```

I'm getting the following routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"issues", :matter_id=>#<Matter id: 2, name: "Wilson", user_id: nil, created_at: "2011-03-23 18:19:40", updated_at: "2011-03-23 18:19:40">, :id=>nil}
```

I am trying to get the path like this:

```
<%= link_to issue.content, matter_issue_path(@matter, @issue) %>
```

When I run rake routes it shows that I have the path:

```
matter_issues GET  /matters/:matter_id/issues(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"issues"}
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: can you confirm that @issue is not nil?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406654/no-route-matches-with-nested-resources

this is the answer to your question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try matter_issues_path(@matter, @issue)

I always seem to run into these pluralization gotchas with Rails routing.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks! Can't believe I wasted an hour on that.

Comment: Solved my problem, although it seemed a little bit weird that rake routes show it as matter_issue and the s needs to be added, but oh well

Comment: You just saved me from what certainly would have been another hour of frustration, and I learned something I didn't know before (that you have to pass in appropriate parameters to those paths when needed).  Thanks!

Comment: This was a huge help.  You did a much better job in two seconds than they did in all of the official Rails Guides on Routing.