# No route matches with Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, routes, nested, associations

I have two associated tables. `Venues` and `Specials`. A `venue` can have many `specials`. Once a user has created a venue I wish to allow them to create a special on the `venues#index` page. By using nested resources I have achieved the desired URL: `/venues/5/specials/new`.

However, my current code results with: `No route matches {:controller=>"specials", :format=>nil}`

I'm guessing the error is with my `SpecialsController` and the `def new` and `def create` functions. 
I would like the URL to take me to a form page where I can enter new data for the specials

```
<%= link_to 'Add Special', new_venue_special_path(venue) %>



App1::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :venues do 
    resources :specials
end


def new
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
      @special = @venue.specials.build
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @special }
       end
      end


  def create
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
    @special = @venue.specials.build(params[:special])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @special.save
        format.html { redirect_to @special, notice: 'Special was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @special, status: :created, location: @special }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @special.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Backtrace

```
Started GET "/venues/4/specials/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-06 23:36:01 +0200
  Processing by SpecialsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"venue_id"=>"4"}
  [1m[36mVenue Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "venues".* FROM "venues" WHERE "venues"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "4"]]
Rendered specials/_form.html.erb (1.9ms)
Rendered specials/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 97ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"specials", :format=>nil}):
    1: <%= form_for(@special) do |f| %>
    2:   <% if @special.errors.any? %>
    3:     <div id="error_explanation">
    4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@special.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this special from being saved:</h2>
  app/views/specials/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_specials__form_html_erb__2784079234875518470_70162904892440'
  app/views/specials/new.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_specials_new_html_erb__115378566176177893_70162906293160'
  app/controllers/specials_controller.rb:30:in `new'

Rendered /Users/andrewlynch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.7ms)
```

Comment: Show us the code of the current form

Comment: Please paste your routes, and your SpecialsController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
redirect_to @special
```

this will default to "specials_path", but you're using venue_special_path

you probably want:

```
redirect_to [@venue, @special]
```

and in the form you will need the same:

```
<%= form_for([@venue, @special]) do |f| %>
```

basically - the issue is that you have a nested resource... which means that every place where you are declaring a url path (including implicit places like form_for) has to be replaced with both the @venue and the @special, instead of just the @special.

you may come across this same "bug" elsewhere in your generated scaffold code... just do the same thing and you should be good.

Comment: Hi I'm still getting No route matches {:controller=>"specials", :format=>nil}

Comment: Ok, can you paste the full backtrace into your questio n? what line of code is causing the error?

Comment: I replaced `format.html { redirect_to @special, notice: 'Special was successfully created.' }` with `format.html { redirect_to [@venue, @special], notice: 'Special was successfully created.' }` and I'm still getting `No route matches {:controller=>"specials", :format=>nil}` should `.build` in `def new` not be `.create`

Comment: Yes as I said - please paste the full backtrace of the error (from your logs) so we can tell which line of code is causing the error. Not just the short error message (ie `No Route...`) what we need is the full trace - should be at least twenty lines of ruby filenames...

Comment: Ok, and you problem is... not in any of the code you posted above ;)

And the solution is the same as I've already given you: but you need to do it in the "form_for. I'll add it to my answer.